# merger one row with null values to not null values of another row mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to merge two rows into one.The below format is in the database.

```
+----+---------+-----------------------+-------------------------+
| id |  appid  |        photo          |         signature       |
+====+=========+=======================+=========================+
| 1  | 10001   | 10001.photograph.jpg  |    NULL                 |
| 2  | 10001   | NULL                  |    10001.signature.jpg  |
+----+---------+-----------------------+-------------------------+
```

I want a mysql query so that i can fetch data like below,

```
  +--------+------------------------+-------------------------+
  | appid  |  photo                 |    signature            |
  +========+========================+=========================+
  |10001   | 10001.photograph.jpg   |   10001.signature.jpg   |
  +--------+------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Kindly suggest...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `max` function

```
select appid,
max(photo) photo,
max(signature) signature
from test
group by appid
```

[`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbe37/1)

Answer (score 0):

This should do this:

```
select t1.appid,t1.photo,t2.signature from mytable t1 join mytable t2 on t1.appid=t2.appid where t1.id=1 and t2.id=2
```